# Trouble running Grails application on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails, ubuntu

I'm trying to deploy a Grails application to a Tomcat container, running on Ubuntu. I was trying to do "everything right", but still can't get it to work. Any ideas?

- I'm running "Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS". I installed the Tomcat that is bundled with Ubuntu (6.0.35). I know Grails can use a lot of memory, so I raised the memory allocated to the JVM to 512MB. The example applications supplied with Tomcat work fine.
- On my PC (running Windows 7) I installed Grails (latest version: 2.3.7) and NetBeans (version: 7.4).
- I created a very simple "Hello world" Grails application. I have some trouble running it on my PC (another question I just posted), but it compiles just fine and I can create a War-file without problems. By running "grails war".
- I've used the Tomcat "Web Application Manager" to upload the War-file. It is put in /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps as it should, unpacked and everything looks fine.
- But when I try to start the application (choosing "Start" in the manager), I get a "FAIL - Application at context path /MyTestApp could not be started" message. I've tried to restart Tomcat, but get the same problem.

When I look at the Tomcat log (catalina.out), this is logged:

```
2014-03-14 20:24:32,148 [http-8080-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context
initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplication' defined in ServletContext
resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701) Caused by:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2534)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.AsyncContext
```

It seems like the "javax.servlet.AsyncContext" class couldn't be found. The Grails documentation says that running Grails on Tomcat is a piece of cake, and that nothing should go wrong... The "javax.servlet.AsyncContext" class seems to have something to do with "Servlet 3.0", but I don't know much about Java EE. I just thought latest-version-of-everything would work out of the box...

Is there anything I need to install on the server? Anything to add to Tomcat? Or some configuration I should change in my application?

I'd be very grateful for any help! :-)

/Anders from Sweden

Comment: Can you post your BuildConfig.groovy I think you might be targeting Tomcat 7 instead of 6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a piece of cake if an appropriate version of Tomcat with this version of Grails is used. :)

Latest version of Grails uses Servlet 3.0 and embedded Tomcat 7.0.52.1 (used during run-app) by default and I doubt it will be compatible with Tomcat 6.0.35. But you can downgrade the servlet version to 2.5 or 2.4 according to your need as:

```
//BuildConfig.groovy (first line)
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" //2.4 or 2.5
```

Comment: LOL. It is still a doubt. I will be more than happy if you add any other possibility. @JoshuaMoore

Comment: Aha. Thanks! :-) Well, I thought it would be something like that.

It could take forever to patch two versions together, so I downloaded Tomcat 7 to my Ubuntu instead. (From the Apache homepage - version 7.0.52.) There was good documentation on the net on how to install it.

But I still don't get it to work. Now I get a different error in catalina.out: [www.agodata.se/TomcatError.txt](http://www.agodata.se/TomcatError.txt)

Any idea what may be causing it?

Comment: Ah - found it myself. (An error in the database connection.) Problem solved! Thanks for your help, both of you.

Comment: There's an unresolved bug with Grails 2.4 preventing downgrading to Tomcat 6.

Comment: According to this Jira case: https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11466 this bug was supposed to be fixed in 2.4.1 however it seems to be back in 2.4.3. Can anyone confirm?